# How do you add attribute to array element with xml2js?

Tags: node.js, json, xml, typescript, xml2js

I'm trying to figure out how to add attributes to an array element

I get an error `Error: Invalid character in name` when trying to build the following XML from an object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Requests xmlns="http://example.com">
    <Request>
    </Request>
    <Request>
    </Request>
</Requests>
```

Here is my object

```js
let myObject = {
 Requests:[
   {$:{xmlns:"http://example.com"}},
   {Request:{}},
   {Request:{}}
  ]
}
let builder = new xml2js.Builder();
let xml = builder.buildObject(myObject);
console.log(xml)
```

I've also tried wrapping the name in quotes

```js
{"$":{"xmlns":"http://example.com"}},
```

Stripping out the attribute declaration altogether produces the desired XML but obviously leaves out the needed attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Requests>
    <Request>
    </Request>
    <Request>
    </Request>
</Requests>
```

Comment: Try to do opposite: parse the XML and look at a resulting object and compare it to your object that you are trying to use.

Comment: I tried that, even though it is valid XML, javascript doesn't treat "Requests" as an array, just a simple object and it actually won't see more than one child "Request"

Comment: Your XML look like Requests is an object and Request is array because this tag repeats several times,

Comment: Hmm, but check out the last code example, the object builds to the XML format I'm looking for, just without an attribute on Requests.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should try this:

```
let myObject = {
 Requests:{
   $:{xmlns:"http://example.com"},
   Request:[{}, {}]
}
```